# CDF for combination of discrete and continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\bar{x}, \sigma_{x}^2)$, $W \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_{w}^2)$, and $A$ has Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p_1$.

How to calculate CDF $F(z)$ of random variable $Z=AX+W$? Can this be answered without use of Lebesgue integral?

This question is related to calculation of minimum mean square estimator (MMSE) of random variable $x$. For that calculation one needs to evaluate $E[x|z]$. Evaluating the conditional mean one must among other things evaluate $p(z)$.
$$E[x|z] = \int x p(x|z) dx =\int x \frac{p(z|x)p(x)}{p(z)} dx = \frac{1}{p(z)} \int x p(z|x)p(x)dx$$
(integral limits are assumed)

Comment: You will need to integrate in any case.  Step 1: get cdf of Y=AX.  Step 2: get char. functions y and w (Fourier transforms of cdf) for Y and W.  Step 3: z=wy. Step 4: Inverse transform of z leads to cdf of Z.

Comment: I don't know how to evaluate $P\{Y \leq \epsilon\} = P\{(A=0, X \in (-\infty, \infty)) \cup  (A=1, X \leq \epsilon)\}$ for $\epsilon \geq 0$

Comment: Maybe $1-p_1 + p_1 \Phi_{X}(\epsilon)$. Where $\Phi_{X}$ is CDF of $X$.

Comment: $P(Y\le y)=p_1\Phi_X(y)$ for $y\lt 0$ and $=1-p_1+p_1\Phi_X(y)$ for $y\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: this calculation is to get the pdf, using convolution, rather than Fourier transform.

To save tedium in Latex, I simplifying symbols. $m=\bar{x}$, $v=\sigma^2$, $p=p_1$.

$f_Z(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-u)^2}{2v_w}}}{\sqrt{2\pi v_w}}(p\frac{ e^{-\frac{(u-m)^2}{2v_x}}}{\sqrt{2\pi v_x}}+(1-p)\delta(u))du=pf_1(x)+(1-p)f_2(x)$
$f_2(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi v_w}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2v_w}}$

Calculation of $f_1(x)$ is tedious, but straightforward.

$f_1(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(v_x+v_w)}}e^{-h(x)}$  where $h(x)=\frac{1}{2v_xv_w}(\frac{(xv_x+mv_w)^2}{v_x+v_w}-v_wx^2-v_xm^2)=\frac{(x-m)^2}{2(v_x+v_w)}$

Comment: Should be $f_2(x)=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{2\pi v_w}}e^{-\frac{1}{2v_w}x^2}$ also, in $f_{Z}(x)$, $\sqrt{2\pi v_w}$ is missing before $(1-p)\delta(u)$.

Comment: @Valjean You're right. I corrected the answer.

Comment: The integral to get $f_1$ is an ordinary (not Lebesgue) integral.  The $f_2$ integral is not the usual pure math. approach.  Here a Stieltjes integral would be used - not Lebesgue either.

Comment: $f_1(x)$ is also incorrect. $f_1(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{W}(z-u) f_{X}(u) du$. $f_1(x)$ is distribution of $X+W$ where $X$ and W are independent and Gaussian. I know that it can be shown that $X+W \sim \mathcal(\bar{x} + \bar{w}, \sigma_{x}^2 + \sigma_{w}^2)=\mathcal(\bar{x}, \sigma_{x}^2 + \sigma_{w}^2)$. With your help I got the final answer $f_{Z}(z)=p_1\mathcal{N}(z;\bar{x}, \sigma_{x}^2 + \sigma_{w}^2) + (1-p_1)\mathcal{N}(z;0,\sigma_{w}^2)$. If you agree, you can correct your answer if you want, and I will accept it.

Comment: You're right again.  I made a sign error in getting $h(x)$.